# rails radio buttons and adding string to label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form

I am trying to set up a group of radio buttons in rails using simple_form. The options should come from a map.

In simple form, I saw there the   `:collection`  symbol can retrieve a collection (but only an array of arrays and not a hash).

How can I display a radio button collections with custom labels (ideally from a hash)?

Here is what I tried so far. Can I concatenate the symbol with an a string for a label?

```
#Payment.rb
OPTIONS = [[14, 19], [21,29], [30,39]] #ideally this would be a hash 

#new.html.erb
     <%= f.input :duration, 
      :collection =>  [ [14, 19.to_s], [21,29.to_s], [30,39.to_s] ], 
      :label_method => :last.concat(" days"), 
      :value_method => :first, 
      :as => :radio %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly - you can use lambdas in :label_method. For example:

```
:label_method => lambda { |a| a.first.to_s + a.last.to_s }
```